# Bootstrap Modal not popping up when clicking button

Tags: html, jquery, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal, popupwindow

I'm trying to add a modal when the user clicks on the 'Add' button under 'Categories.' When I use just the code for the modal in js fiddle, it works, but when I add all of the code from the current file, it doesn't. Have tried moving jquery cdn around and also making a separate div container for the modal, but not able to get it. Any help is appreciated.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

    <title>Inventory Management System</title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.5.4/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-q2kxQ16AaE6UbzuKqyBE9/u/KzioAlnx2maXQHiDX9d4/zp8Ok3f+M7DPm+Ib6IU"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-pQQkAEnwaBkjpqZ8RU1fF1AKtTcHJwFl3pblpTlHXybJjHpMYo79HY3hIi4NKxyj"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/main.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Navbar -->
    <?php  include_once("./templates/header.php"); ?>
    <br /><br />
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="card mx-auto">
            <img
              src="./images/user.png"
              style="width: 60%"
              class="card-img-top mx-auto"
              alt="Card image cap"
            />
            <div class="card-body">
              <h4 class="card-title">Profile Info</h4>
              <p class="card-text">
                <i class="fa fa-user">&nbsp;</i>Brian Liang
              </p>
              <p class="card-text"><i class="fa fa-user">&nbsp;</i>Admin</p>
              <p class="card-text">Last Login : xxxx-xx-xx</p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary"
                ><i class="fa fa-edit">&nbsp; </i>Edit Profile</a
              >
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <div class="jumbotron" style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
            <h1>Welcome Admin,</h1>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <iframe
                  src="http://free.timeanddate.com/clock/i7l8nwj9/n199/szw160/szh160/hoca32/hbw10/hfcc00/cf100/hnca32/fas30/facfff/fdi86/mqcfff/mqs2/mql3/mqw4/mqd70/mhcfff/mhs2/mhl3/mhw4/mhd70/mmcfff/mml4/mmw4/mmd98/hhcfff/hhs2/hmcfff/hms2/hscfff"
                  frameborder="0"
                  width="160"
                  height="160"
                ></iframe>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <h4 class="card-title">New Orders</h4>
                    <p class="card-text">
                      Here you can make new invoices and create new orders.
                    </p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">New Orders</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <p></p>
      <p></p>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h4 class="card-title">Categories</h4>
              <p class="card-text">
                Here you can manage your categories and can add parent and sub
                categories
              </p>
              <a
                href="#"
                data-toggle="modal"
                data-target="#exampleModal"
                class="btn btn-primary"
                >Add</a
              >
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Manage</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h4 class="card-title">Brands</h4>
              <p class="card-text">
                Here you can manage your brand and can add a new brand
              </p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Add</a>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Manage</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h4 class="card-title">Products</h4>
              <p class="card-text">
                Here you can manage your products and can add new products
              </p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Add</a>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Manage</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Modal -->
      <div class="row">
        <div
          class="modal fade"
          id="exampleModal"
          tabindex="-1"
          role="dialog"
          aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
          aria-hidden="true"
        >
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                <button
                  type="button"
                  class="close"
                  data-dismiss="modal"
                  aria-label="Close"
                >
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">...</div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button
                  type="button"
                  class="btn btn-secondary"
                  data-dismiss="modal"
                >
                  Close
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
                  Save changes
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

The code that you useis only available for `Bootstrap 4`, but in the header, you are including the `Bootstrap 5` that have changed some parameters regarding `modals` :

- To trigger a modal:

  ```
   // OLD WAY
   data-toggle="modal"
   data-target="#exampleModal"
   // NEW WAY
   data-bs-toggle="modal"
   data-bs-target="#exampleModal"
  ```
- Declaring a modal :

  ```
   <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
         <div class="modal-dialog">
           <div class="modal-content">
             <div class="modal-header">
               <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
               <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
             </div>
             <div class="modal-body">
               ...
             </div>
             <div class="modal-footer">
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
  ```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

    <title>Inventory Management System</title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.5.4/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-q2kxQ16AaE6UbzuKqyBE9/u/KzioAlnx2maXQHiDX9d4/zp8Ok3f+M7DPm+Ib6IU"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-pQQkAEnwaBkjpqZ8RU1fF1AKtTcHJwFl3pblpTlHXybJjHpMYo79HY3hIi4NKxyj"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/main.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Navbar -->
    <?php  include_once("./templates/header.php"); ?>
    <br /><br />
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="card mx-auto">
            <img
              src="./images/user.png"
              style="width: 60%"
              class="card-img-top mx-auto"
              alt="Card image cap"
            />
            <div class="card-body">
              <h4 class="card-title">Profile Info</h4>
              <p class="card-text">
                <i class="fa fa-user">&nbsp;</i>Brian Liang
              </p>
              <p class="card-text"><i class="fa fa-user">&nbsp;</i>Admin</p>
              <p class="card-text">Last Login : xxxx-xx-xx</p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary"
                ><i class="fa fa-edit">&nbsp; </i>Edit Profile</a
              >
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <div class="jumbotron" style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
            <h1>Welcome Admin,</h1>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <iframe
                  src="http://free.timeanddate.com/clock/i7l8nwj9/n199/szw160/szh160/hoca32/hbw10/hfcc00/cf100/hnca32/fas30/facfff/fdi86/mqcfff/mqs2/mql3/mqw4/mqd70/mhcfff/mhs2/mhl3/mhw4/mhd70/mmcfff/mml4/mmw4/mmd98/hhcfff/hhs2/hmcfff/hms2/hscfff"
                  frameborder="0"
                  width="160"
                  height="160"
                ></iframe>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <h4 class="card-title">New Orders</h4>
                    <p class="card-text">
                      Here you can make new invoices and create new orders.
                    </p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">New Orders</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <p></p>
      <p></p>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h4 class="card-title">Categories</h4>
              <p class="card-text">
                Here you can manage your categories and can add parent and sub
                categories
              </p>
              <a
                href="#"
                class="btn btn-primary"
                        data-bs-toggle="modal" 
                data-bs-target="#exampleModal"
                >Add</a
              >
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Manage</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h4 class="card-title">Brands</h4>
              <p class="card-text">
                Here you can manage your brand and can add a new brand
              </p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Add</a>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Manage</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h4 class="card-title">Products</h4>
              <p class="card-text">
                Here you can manage your products and can add new products
              </p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Add</a>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Manage</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Modal -->
      <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                ...
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

You are probably getting your bootstrap versions mixed up. I have tested your code using bootstrap 4 and bootstrap 5 and can confirm it works on bootstrap 4 but does not on bootstrap 5, you can fix your code easily by replacing your bootstrap 5 script imports with bootstrap 4, or you can port your code to bootstrap 5.

Bootstrap 5 recently changed the way modals are triggered, which is why it does not work on 5 but does work on 4.

The following head works for me

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<title>Inventory Management System</title>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.5.4/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-q2kxQ16AaE6UbzuKqyBE9/u/KzioAlnx2maXQHiDX9d4/zp8Ok3f+M7DPm+Ib6IU" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: You can read about modals for bootstrap 5 here, https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/