# Modals not working in Bootstrap for Rails 7

Tags: bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5, ruby-on-rails-7

I'm using the Bootstrap gem in Rails 7.

I'm just trying to get a simple Bootstrap modal working.

The dropdowns in the app work fine, so I assume JS is setup correctly, but just in case:

`importmap.rb`:

```
pin "application", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/turbo-rails", to: "turbo.min.js", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/stimulus", to: "stimulus.min.js", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/stimulus-loading", to: "stimulus-loading.js", preload: true
pin_all_from "app/javascript/controllers", under: "controllers"
pin "popper", to: 'popper.js', preload: true
pin "bootstrap", to: 'bootstrap.min.js', preload: true
```

`assets.rb`:

```
...
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( bootstrap.min.js popper.js)
```

`application.js`:

```
import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"
import "controllers"
import "popper"
import "bootstrap"
```

`application.html.erb`:

```
...
<%= javascript_importmap_tags %>
...
```

My view:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bd-example-modal-lg">Large modal</button>

<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      Test modal
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So it's just a simple modal, copied from Bootstrap's docs, and when I click on the modal button, absolutely nothing happens.

Please don't just link me to a Stackoverflow article because I've literally just spent an hour going through all those.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bootstrap Modal not popping up when clicking button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65406733/bootstrap-modal-not-popping-up-when-clicking-button)

Comment: Or this? [Bootstrap 5 modal not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67534348/bootstrap5-modal-not-showing)

Comment: Or this? [Bootstrap 5 modal does not display at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66530042/bootstrap-5-modal-not-display-at-all)

Answer (score 1):

As soon as I posted this, I found the answer. Typical!

Anyway, the answer is to replace `data-toggle` and `data-target` with `data-bs-toggle` and `data-bs-target`.